# php mySQL room booking calendar showing wrong dates as booked

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I have a php MySql booking calendar, which shows whether the room is booked or not on a date basis. The problem is, it shows the wrong info. For example, if I book 5-6 it should have marked the 5th red, meaning it was booked on 5th. It shows 6th but by 6, 12:00:00 the room will be free. Another example: If I book 23-25 it shows 24, 25 as booked, but it should show 23-25, dont know where the problem is.

Here is the code:

```
  function getAllRooms($date,$month,$year)
{
    global $db;
    $where = ' ';
    if ($_GET['room_type'] != '') {
        $where .= " HAVING room_type = '".$_GET['room_type']."'";
    }

    $sql = "SELECT room_type 
            FROM 
                room 
            GROUP BY 
                room_type 
            $where
            ";
    /*echo $sql;
    exit;*/
    $result = $db->Execute($sql);;
    $room = '';
    while (!$result->EOF) {
        $qs     = '?room_type='.$result->fields('room_type').'&month='.$month.'&year='.$year;
        $total  = get_total_rooms_by_type($result->fields('room_type'),$date,$month,$year);
        $room   .=
        '<div class="'.$result->fields('room_type').'"> 

            <a href="'.BASE_URL.'room_detail.php'.$qs.'">
                '.$result->fields('room_type').' ('.$total.')
            </a>
        </div>';
        $result->MoveNext();
    }
    $result->Close;
    return $room;
}
function get_total_rooms_by_type($room_type,$date,$month,$year)
{
    global $db;
    $_newdate   = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$date;
    $sql            = "SELECT room_id FROM room where room_type = '$room_type' ";
    $room_results   = $db->Execute($sql);
    $room_ids       = array();
    while (!$room_results->EOF) {
        $room_ids[] = $room_results->fields('room_id');
        $room_results->MoveNext();
    }
    $room_results_str = implode(',',$room_ids);
    $where = ' where 1 = 1 ';
    $available = 1;
    if ($_GET['booking_status'] == '1') {
        $where .= ' and (booking_status = 1 or booking_status = 2)';
        $available = 0;
    } else if ($_GET['booking_status'] == '2') {
        $where .= ' and (booking_status = 2)';
        $available = 0;
    } 
    $sql = "select count(room_id) from bookings 
            $where 
                and checkin <= '$_newdate'
                and '$_newdate' <= checkout
                and room_id in ($room_results_str)
            ";
    if ($available == 0) {
        return $db->GetOne($sql);

    } else {
        return count($room_ids) - $db->GetOne($sql);
    }


}
function draw_calendar_room($month,$year){

    /* draw table */
    $calendar = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">';

    /* table headings */
    $headings = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$headings).'</td></tr>';


    /* days and weeks vars now ... */
    $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_this_week = 1;
    $day_counter = 0;
    $dates_array = array();

    /* row for week one */
    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';

    /* print "blank" days until the first of the current week */
    for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>';
        $days_in_this_week++;
    endfor;

    /* keep going with days.... */
    for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day">';;

            $calendar.= '<div class="day-number" style=" padding:5px 5px 45px;background-color:'.getRoomColor($list_day,$month,$year).'">'.$list_day.'</div>';

            /** QUERY THE DATABASE FOR AN ENTRY FOR THIS DAY !!  IF MATCHES FOUND, PRINT THEM !! **/


        $calendar.= '</td>';
        if($running_day == 6):
            $calendar.= '</tr>';
            if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
                $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
            endif;
            $running_day = -1;
            $days_in_this_week = 0;
        endif;
        $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
    endfor;

    /* finish the rest of the days in the week */
    if($days_in_this_week < 8):
        for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
            $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>';
        endfor;
    endif;

    /* final row */
    $calendar.= '</tr>';

    /* end the table */
    $calendar.= '</table>';

    /* all done, return result */
    return $calendar;
}
function getRoomColor($date,$month,$year)
{
    global $db;
    $where = ' ';
    if ($_GET['room_id'] != '') {
        $room_id    = $_GET['room_id'];

    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT room_id
                        FROM 
                            room 
                        WHERE
                            room_type = '".$_GET['room_type']."' order by room_number asc
                        ";
        $room_id = $db->GetOne($sql);;
    }
    $_newdate = "$year-$month-$date";
    $sql = "SELECT booking_status
            FROM 
                bookings 
            where 
                checkin <= '$_newdate'
                and 
                '$_newdate' <= checkout
                and 
                room_id = '$room_id'
            ";
    /*echo $sql;
    exit;*/
    $result = $db->GetOne($sql);;
    if ($result == 1) {
        return '#FF0';
    } else if ($result == 2) {
        return '#F00';
    } else {
        return '#64C733';
    }

}
```

Comment: I think  $where 
                and checkin <= '$_newdate'
                and '$_newdate' <= checkout

this sql is not getting the right result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was actually issue of time mismatch. In db I set date time as checkin and checkout but my checking sql  retrieving data with date there were no time consideration.

now added:

```
$_newdate   = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$date . " " . "12:00:00";
```

is working like a charm. !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not much of an answer but..

Well I can go through your code but I am sure you can solve this problem yourself since 
its just logic error I believe.
What you can do is print the all the resulting variable from beginning and
debug through them. That way you will know which line is giving problem.

You can then try to solve it yourself or ask a more precise question here.

Good Luck! :)

Comment: as I am not good at sql thats why i am not getting the error causing things.

Comment: Just print the output values & get the exact error line...
Get the exact sql or variable thats causing problem & we can move on
from there.
Consider this your first sql training :D

P.S. - Just a question.. The value problem.. Is the dates being stored in database is correct? or its the retrieval problem?

Comment: its retrieval problem, like if 5 room booked for  5th to 6th in logic 5th should be booked for one night, but its showing 6th as booked 5th free.

Comment: well, then its a logic problem.. now print the sql that retrieves the dates. If those values are right, your query is correct & move onwards printing all the calculation values.. if not, we need to check the query.
One another way around is change in database design. You can store only first date & time of booking and then number of days of stay. that will simplify your problem...

But first, lets check query